# Is there any wireless technology I can use off-grid?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet-of-things

I need to send some sensor data from a kit car to pit garage. Normally I would use 4G to send the data over the internet but the place where the vehicle will race does not have reception of any kind. I don't know of any technology that allows me to receive information from sensors under these conditions:

1. Must maintain connection within a two kilometer radius
2. It should not take more than 2 seconds to receive packets
3. Must work without Line of Sight (since mounds of earth are expected)
4. up to 1mbit of bandwidth

Comment: Hi JB, welcome to Hardware Recs! By "off-grid", do you also mean without power, or just without cell signal? If the former, your options will be severely limited and won't come close to 1 Mbps of bandwidth. If the latter, you'll probably be limited by how many hills are in the way; 2.4 GHz or 900 MHz directional radio should do 2 km easily, but even 900 MHz is only going to go through a few hills. Any more than that and you'll be looking at something lower frequency, which will probably have less than 1 Mbps of bandwidth and require an FCC license (at least in the US.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean off-grid as in you don't have a cell signal and you need a signal to perform said tasks, if that's the case depending who you use as a mobile carrier you can buy what's called a signal booster through your phone's carrier or you may can even find some 3rd party ones for cheap, most phone carriers also have what is called a FEMTO cell and is kind of similar but usually used for more permanent homes in rural areas. Either way both options should provide you with a signal depending how far away you are and how much interference there is.

Comment: Doesnt it make this non-offgrid then?

Comment: Yes, which is why I was confused at the start of my response, and which is why i said im assuming because i dont know of any technology that can do what he is asking while being "offgrid"

Answer (score 0):

If money is no object then you can use long range Wifi.  Here is one [example](https://www.signalboosters.com/blog/what-is-a-long-range-wifi-network-and-how-does-it-work/). I am not associated with it and I have not used it myself.  But there are many such devices available for rural/farm use.

> **Tenda 5GHZ 16dBi 11ac Outdoor CPE**
>
> - Incredible range up to 6 miles
> - 16dBi dual polarized antenna
> - Wireless data rates up to 450Mbps
> - Robust construction
> - Simple and flexible installation
> - Uses TD-MAX for greater performance
> - Centralized management with CPE Assistant

If one in each car is too expensive, then use something similar to traverse the distance and then use a wifi extender to rebroadcast around the track.

Comment: The antenna suggested by you is a directional antenna. How do you keep a directional antenna orientated exactly in the direction of the receiver in a moving (race) car ?